# Parallel TRIACs driving same load

Tags: triac

I am designing a series of heaters. One of them, actually, is designed for 220V and uses two resistors on series to achieve the power desired. The total current is, on peak, almost 20A. To keep the compatibility with others machines, and based on a lot of other things, the TRIAC which will drive the load will be the BT139-600E. But the maximum current its allow it's 16A.

To solve this problem I have two possibilities. First of them is to separate both resistors(doubling the effective value) and drive them on parallel (each resistor on a different TRIAC, which will limit the current on each to rough 10A).

Another possibility is to keep the connection of resistor as it has been done and put the TRIACs on parallel nor the resistors. In this scheme two TRIACs will drive the same load.

The point is:
If I use two TRIACs on parallel to drive the same load, will the system keep the currents drained by each balanced? On other words, have the TRIACs almost the same impedance at conduction? Are there any other disadvantages of the second solution compared with the first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you should not attempt to parallel triacs as they will not share the load evenly.

As temperature increases the hotter one will hog more current so even if they were perfectly matched to begin with they won't play nicely during operation.

Comment: The issues are mostly due to the heat of the TRIAC? They share the same heat sink and, since it has a cooler to refrigerate, it's not supposed to surpass 40°C (on tests I've verified 29°C).

Comment: So the TRIACs are supposed to be at almost the same temperature.

Comment: It's better on the same heat sink, but there is still no guarantee they'll share current properly. If you can add some resistance in series with each individually (enough to drop a few volts each)...

Comment: Thx very much. In spite of use two bt139 I will use a single bta24. I think it's a safer and cheaper solution.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
this is BTA24-800 from SSR 100 A.tjey use pararel Triact to increase Current

Comment: It doesn't look very healthy anymore. You sure this is a valuable reply to a question from 2015?

Answer (score -1):

I have seen lot of professional lighting equipement, 2 triacs connected in parallel driving 2000 watt lamps.

Comment: My vacuum cleaner switches more than 2kW with a single triac, and I have seen equipment using paralleled triacs too.... Burning....

Comment: It's like tube amplifiers. They use matched components to guarantee success. But they buy the components by the boatload and they test them, then they use parts that got similar results together. You can't just buy two triacs and expect them to be matched.